# error 403 when trying to log in during checkout

Tags: commerce

It's the first time i'm posting on a forum but i've been really stuck with this problem for a few days.
So thanks for your help.

I'm working on a site that's entirely https.
The site uses the anonym checkout  possibilities. I recently observed that when a user wants to connect during checkout (using the "/user" link, I don't use extra pannel to log in), after adding a product to cart or after a purchase, he gets an error 403.
Whatever role he has, he is stuck with this error. The login and the password are correct. And this doesn't happen when we are on another page. It only appears from the moment a user adds a product in the cart.
Then he has to empty the session and cache of the navigator to connect to his account.

I don't understand the problem because I don't have this problem on localhost, the only difference i see between the two server is that i don't use https on the localhost.
That's why i think it's a session problem but i'm not sure.
I tried all the solutions proposed for the settings.php, I don't use secure page (i used to but i uninstalled it because the site is entirely https now).
The site is on a subdomain.

I have made a redirection to htacess to redirect possible entry by http to https with this code:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$https://a.domain.com/$1[R=301,L]

I don't know what else to do, thanks for your help. Sorry if there's a lack of information, just tell me.

Thanks.

Comment: On which URI exactly you're getting 403, `/user`? Check the Rules if you don't have any suspicious triggers reacting on 'adding a product to cart'. Also check watchdog entries, if there is anything extra.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes i'm getting the 403 on '/user'.
Actually the only modification I've made in the rules is to redirect to the cart when a product is added to it.
I added this on the commerce add to cart message rule.
The watchdog entries only give me an access denied without more information.
What's weird is that when we look at the order this one is attributed to the user(whatever the status of the order) but the user can't log in.

Comment: If you're using [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/), you can use it to dump the trace file on `/user` page and it'll give you all the information which module generated 403 code as normally `/user` page doesn't have any permission restriction, see `'access callback'` at [user_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/user_menu).

Comment: Thanks again for your time. I don't know xdebug, but it's not installed on the server and i don't have the access to this one. But if i understand correctly, you think that the problem may come from an other module ?

Comment: Is it possible that the problem comes from the database?
I'm not sure but i think that the problem occured after I've installed the "commerce checkout login" module. I had 403 errors after a purchase when we tried to log in from the /user link. So i uninstall this module but apparently the 403 error is still here. I'm not sure this is related.

Comment: Btw. Does 403 error comes from Drupal or Apache? Is the page is rendered in Drupal-way or it's plain white error?

Comment: The page is rendered in Drupal-ways. In fact the user even seems to be connected, the url is like /users/name but instead of his account, it's the access denied page which is displayed.

Comment: If it's `/users/name`, maybe the user doesn't have permission to view other user profiles? Does it happen for admin as well?

Comment: Yes the problem appears for the admin too.

Comment: If this happens for admin, then it's 403 on demand caused by some contrib module or rule. Scan your modules for `drupal_access_denied()` text and disable suspicious modules, disable suspicious rules, otherwise use xdebug to debug it on your local (make sure you have exact the same db and code-base). Or restore db from when it was working for testing purposes.

Comment: So I've made test on my local with exact db and code-base.
The bug doesn't appear on it, so i think it's a session problem (my local doesn't have ssl on it). So I'll try to install ssl on it to look if the problem is still here.

Comment: Either try to activate SSL on your local, or disable on remote. Check also differences between your settings files if nothing extra is added on the site. If you don't have access to the server and it has Devel, you can access settings file from there. Otherwise if you don't have access to the server, it's a bit limited. Try again, have the exact configuration at your local (including SSL, the same modules, similar variables from settings file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was a session bug with my version of php (5.6.3) the code from [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363219#comment-9366567) contains a workaround:

```
function mymodule_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  $_SESSION['mymodule']['ulogged'] = 1;
}
```